# Obfuscate aspx pages - c# codes are inside aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, obfuscation

Please take a look at this link :
[http://forums.asp.net - Obfuscate aspx pages](http://forums.asp.net/t/2024705.aspx?Obfuscate%20aspx%20pages)
I have the same problem and my problem is how can i obfuscate **aspx** pages with **c#** codes **inside**?
I know for .net dlls we can use :
[Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview)
Or
Other third party programs...
But what about aspx files with c# codes and my purpose is to obfuscate c# method names and strings in that file!

**EDIT** :
My aspx file is like this :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" trace="false" validateRequest="false" EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableViewState="true"%>
<%@ import Namespace="System.IO"%>
....
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
C# Codes...
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="" runat="server">
...
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

obfuscation of aspx(html) part is not important for me and only want to obfuscate C# Codes...

**Edit 2 :**
What is your purpose?
Are you crazy?
No, i'm not.
sometimes i don't have access to Visual Studio and want to write a little project very quickly in a single file with c# codes and gave it to my customer.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i am trying to build something like php and use it.  thats all...

Comment: As the link you provided mentions, you can precompile your aspx pages and obfuscate the binaries you get. Why do you want to obfuscate the aspx pages?

Comment: I think the problem is that they are using inline C# in the .aspx files so they want that obfuscated as well. My suggestion is to not do that. Move the code to aspx.cs files and pre-compile and obfuscate the .dll.

Comment: i know we can separate c# and aspx codes.  but i want to learn how can i obfuscate such these files (aspx codes + c# codes in one file)?

Comment: It appears you've decided on an approach and are looking for confirmation. What do you want to *accomplish* by taking your chosen path?

Comment: inline c# codes are part of asp.net web developing and the answer in asp.net forum ignored the question. just want to learn how can we obfuscate these aspx files like we can do that in php files? what is wrong about this chosen path?

Comment: Please see my Edit 2

Comment: I don't see the need for "obfuscation" based on the edits. If you want quick/easy _compile_ of`cs` or `vb` file into `dll` you can via command line using `csc` or `vbc` respectively.

Comment: And expanding on @EdSF comment, if you could obfuscate the way you want to do it, how would you obfuscate without Visual Studio?

Comment: Ok, so here is how you obfuscate your ASPX file. First, name all your variables using the following scheme `<name of animal><name of planet><quote from famous president translated to Farsi>`. For example, `rhinocerousSaturnSdaqtAvlynFslDrKtabHkmtAst`. Also, make sure you use no loops or repeaters and instead copy paste everything inside the block the appropriate number of times. This will sufficiently obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you said, "how can i obfuscate such these files (aspx codes + c# codes in one file)?" You cannot do that.  You can use the [Code-Behind Model](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303247) which is where you C# code in a separate file.

> **Code-Behind**
>
> Code-behind refers to code for your ASP.NET page that is contained
>   within a separate class file. This allows a clean separation of your
>   HTML from your presentation logic.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any third party software to obfuscate blobloblo.cs files not dll files?

Comment: @MoonLight think "library" - which can then live in a non ASP.net context/project, at which point you can use what you already mentioned - Dotfuscator. Because by _separating_ your core logic (but not those needed by the ASP.net pipeline), they will, in fact just be a `dll` referenced in your web site. Hth...

Comment: You cannot obfuscate the source code (blobloblo.cs). You can obfuscate the resulting compiled source which is the DLL.  And @MoonLight is correct.  You can move your protected **Intellectual Property** into external project that is protected with Dotfuscator.